Lagrange points for figure eight orbit
The figure 8 orbit is the only known stable orbital configuration for 3 bodies of equal mass. Are there islands of stability, analogous to Lagrange points for 2 orbiting bodies, that trace their way around the figure 8?

There are other stable orbits for three bodies, such as a central body and two planets, or a central body, a planet and a moon.

@JamesK edited, thanks

@ScienceSnake it's a good point. I can hear the joke now CARSON: the figure-eight orbit is so stable... AUDIENCE: (in unison) How stable is it?" I think that in orbital there are several different flavors of stability; for example see the first paragraph of Wikipedia's Lyapunov stability

I would somewhat hesitantly say "no"... Because "analogous" isn't really possible.  In the 2 body system, you can choose a rotating frame in which the planet is at rest.  In this rotating frame, you can consider the pseudo-potential, and find there are the five lagrange points.  But what is the analogy with a figure of 8 orbit? There isn't a way to get a rotating frame and find a pseudopotential... so there isn't an analogy to the Lagrange points.  I'm hesitant because someone might think of another way to form the analogy.

@ScienceSnake a quick question posted in Math SE just might bring an authoritative and comprehensive answer.
